# how to make growing flower animation between two views

Tags: iphone, ipad, animation

i have a `UIButton` in a **viewcontroller's** view, i wrote action method form that i am going to  another view controller's view. Now i am trying to implement *animation* between to views.i tried with many types one of the type *animation* is shown below

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"flipping view" context:nil];

[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];

[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut];

[self.view addSubview:anotherView];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This animation is working well but i am trying to implement some **"growing flower animation"**(name may be different) means the other view pop up from the button co-ordinates`and occupy entire screen.my custom`button` co-ordinates are **(500,500,20,20)**.can any one suggest me for implementing this  *animation*.
Thank you.

Comment: Go to art school? Perhaps you should rephrase your question: what aspects of programming do you want help with, and what have you tried?

Comment: Thank you Pontus.. I re formated my question.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved by various methods. 
You can use:- 
1 )

1. Core animations
2. UIImage class's animations
3. Cocos 2D
4. UIAnimation Classes (by simple changing the frames)
5. ..and many more

It actually depends on your requirements, and your comfortable level with these classes/technologies.

If you just want to display growing flower, then the simpler (but not the optimized, and best) solution is to create different images,and put them in array, and then animate it

A similar example is available at: -
[Animating images](http://appsamuck.com/day2.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you have step by step images of growing flower images, then you can simply implement this. Write a function to implement simple implementation,

```
    NSMutableArray * images;

//allocates the images array.
images = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

//loops till the 18images are added into array.
for (int index = 1; index < 19; index++) {

    //get the image name.
    NSString * imageName  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Animation%d",index];

    //get the path for the image in resourse file.
    NSString * path  = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:imageName ofType:@"png"];     

    //allocate and own the image object for the particular image.
    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];     

    //adds it to array.
    [images addObject:image];

    //release after adding.
    [image release];

    //remove the useless pointer.
    image = nil;
}   

//give the pointer to the array holding the images.
imageView.animationImages = images; 

//after using it, release it.
[images release];

//remove the useless pointer
images = nil;

//set animation duration
imageView.animationDuration = 3.00;

//start animate
[imageView startAnimating];
```

After when you want to stop the animation you can simply call

```
[imageView stopAnimation];
```

You have another choice of

```
imageView.repeatCount = 1;
```

imageView is an instance of uiimageView, allocated one.